# CSS border being trapezoid but not rectangle

Tags: css

In CSS, if I set an individual border (e.g. `border-right`) after setting the global `border`, with a different color, this border looks like a trapezoid, not a rectangle which is what I would like. I kind of understand the rationale behind this, because CSS doesn't know which border I want to prioritize. But is there a way to make this individual border a complete rectangle, instead of missing two small corners?

Thanks!

See https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11954789/44997869-48573580-af66-11e8-9169-b1d53e13edc4.png for an image.

Comment: Which one do you want to prioritize?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I want to prioritize the individual border (the `border-right` in my example)

Comment: @Uli Thanks! That seems to work.